# Can't connect WinForms application with the ASP.NET MVC application database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I placed the shared classes in a class library and referenced it in the two projects, theses are the classes I'm using in the class library:

```
namespace SharedModels
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<UserTask> Tasks { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    [Table("Task")]
    public class UserTask
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public string Sataus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<UserTask> Tasks { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Tasks)
                .WithMany(t => t.Users)
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.ToTable("UserTask");
                    x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    x.MapRightKey("TaskId");
                });
        }
    }

}
```

In this class I used the common members I need in both application,
The MVC app works fine, but he WinForms doesn't seem to see the database to read from it, there is no error.
I have a listBox that get populated from the database:

```
listBoxUsers.DataSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
```

but it returns null.
this method also returns null, I use it in the Log In form:

```
public async Task<bool> VerifyUserNamePassword(string userName, string password)
{
    var usermanager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    return await usermanager.FindAsync(userName, password) != null;
}
```

I can't figure out what's going on, before the class library I used two separate EF code first models for the same entities in both application and it was a mess, however the application was working!

Comment: Are you sure that both applications use the same connection string? Could you post your app.config and web.config?

Comment: I can't thank you enough, your comment reminds me that I changed the connection string in one application, thanks very much.